# Why is isset() returning FALSE for a boolean variable that is set and is TRUE?

Tags: php

I have spent the last 20 minutes trying to work out the cause for this issue.

Firstly I will do

```
$this->is_csu = TRUE;
```

In a separate class I call isset, isset returns FALSE, if I immediately echo the variable it will return TRUE.

```
echo var_dump(isset($this->is_csu));
echo var_dump($this->is_csu);
die();
```

Results in an output of

```
bool(false) bool(true)
```

I'm sure there is some technical reason to why this is happening, but it is beyond me right now.

Hopefully someone can shed some light on this.

Comment: Have you declared it in your class definition, e.g. `class X { private $is_csu; }`?

Comment: Please provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that demonstrates this problem.

Comment: Sorry, i need more code, i think the problem is that you are creating 2 difference instances of this class. So if you change in one instance the other will not change.

Comment: Yes I have declared them, it is used perfectly fine in other classes. We don't check if its set in those classes as there is no need to do so. In this case there is and that is how I have found the problem.

Comment: You don't need to echo `var_dump`s..

Comment: Apologies for the lack of code, I am going to close this question until I can provide you with an appropriate example of my issue. Thanks for the consideration.

Comment: @tandu [edit]... thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2):

Your probably extending a class with a private member.

See the [PHP Examples](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php) on how this is treated.

The only way for me to get your output is by using PHPs magic methods on a class, for example:

```
class A
{
        public function __isset($n)
        {
                $this->$n = TRUE;
        }
}

$bar = new A();
var_dump(isset($bar->foo));
var_dump($bar->foo);
```

Output:

```
bool(false)
bool(true)
```

Though I think you'd already knew if you were using one of those.

Comment: No, because it's not defined in the extending class. You can just $this->AnythingYouLike = "Foobar". It's just a variable. Edit: That was at your previous comment, not the newly edited.

Comment: If that's the case, and the OP is setting `$this->foo`, how would the fact it's extending another class affect the output? If he set the value, `isset()` shouldn't return `false`.

Comment: As someone else already said, there's something bogus with his output. A variable can never be unset (isset() === FALSE) and still contain TRUE. If it contain's TRUE, it's obviously set, ergo isset() === TRUE. My prediction is he's not calling those var_dump at the same place as the question suggests, but rather in different places of his project.

Comment: That is my suspicion as well.

Comment: ccKep and Jon, I can confirm the var_dumps are exactly straight after each other in the code, referencing exactly the same variable. Im working on trying to replicate this outside of the code I am working on so you can all have a far clearer example - which Is why I want to close this until I have time to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I know its a very old question , but it occurred to me as well and I could not figure out why.

The reason was in the end that this was a private or protected member , so though you could get its value, the isset returned false.

var_dump is problematic as it is doing reflection .